# Unable to display multiple line charts in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, chart.js

I am very new to java-script and was trying to learn how to add multiple line charts to my web UI.  But unfortunately I am stuck with a problem, I am unable to add multiple line charts to my web UI.
I am unable to understand what I am doing wrong. I tried several approaches but couldn't find the solution.

Appreciate the help!

Below is my code for your reference.

```js
var xValues = [50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150];
    var yValues = [7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 10, 11, 14, 14, 15];

    function displayPanel(i) {
      var panel = document.getElementById('panel');
      panel.innerHTML += `
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
             <form>
                <label id="paramname_${i}" for="paramvalue">${i}</label>
                <input type="text" id="paramvalue_${i}" name="param" value=${i} readonly>  
              </form>
         </div>
         <div id="chart_${i}" class="column">
             <canvas id="myChart${i}" style="width:100%;max-width:600px"></canvas>
         </div>
    </div>`;

      new Chart("myChart" + i, {
        type: "line",
        data: {
          labels: xValues,
          datasets: [{
            fill: false,
            lineTension: 0,
            backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,255,1.0)",
            borderColor: "rgba(0,0,255,0.1)",
            data: yValues
          }]
        },
        options: {
          legend: {
            display: false
          },
          scales: {
            yAxes: [{
              ticks: {
                min: 6,
                max: 16
              }
            }],
          }
        }
      });
      new Chart("myChart" + i, {
        type: "line",
        data: {
          labels: xValues,
          datasets: [{
            fill: false,
            lineTension: 0,
            backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,255,1.0)",
            borderColor: "rgba(0,0,255,0.1)",
            data: yValues
          }]
        },
        options: {
          legend: {
            display: false
          },
          scales: {
            yAxes: [{
              ticks: {
                min: 6,
                max: 16
              }
            }],
          }
        }
      });
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      displayPanel(i);
    }
```

```css
<style>.column {
      float: left;
      align-self: right;
      width: 50%;
      padding: 10px;
    }

    .row {
      content: "";
      clear: both;
      display: table;
    }

    </style>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js"></script>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <body>
      <div id="panel"></


----------


div>
    </body>
```

```
  function addParamsToPanel(parameter, paramValue, isDisplay, i) {
    console.log("XXXX" + parameter);
    if (isDisplay) {
      displayPanel(parameter, paramValue,i);
    }
  }

  function updatePanel(paramList, valueList) {
    param = paramList.toString().split(',');
    paramValue = valueList.toString().split(',');
    for (var i = 0; i < param.length; i++) {
      var p = document.createElement("div");
      var checkBox = document.createElement("input");
      var label = document.createElement("label");
      checkBox.type = "checkbox";
      checkBox.id = param[i];
      p.appendChild(checkBox);
      p.appendChild(label);
      document.getElementById("cboxes").appendChild(p);
      label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(param[i]));
      document.getElementById(param[i]).checked = true;
      addParamsToPanel(param[i], paramValue[i], document.getElementById(param[i]).checked, i);
    }
  }

  function displayPanel(parameter, paramValue, i) {
    var panel = document.getElementById('panel');    
    var today = new Date();
    var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
    var newChart = 'paramChart_' + parameter;
    panel.innerHTML += `
    <div class="row">
        <!--div class="col-md-9 col-lg-10 col-sm-11"-->
        <div class="column">
          <form>
            <label id="paramname_${parameter}" for="paramvalue">${parameter}</label>
            <input type="text" id="paramvalue_${parameter}" name="param" value=${paramValue} readonly>  
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="chart_${i}" class="column">
          <canvas id=${newChart} style="width:100%;max-height:100px;max-width:700px;border: solid;rgb(4, 31, 65);"></canvas>
        </div>
    `;

    console.log(newChart.value);
    var chart = new Chart(newChart, {
      type: "line",
      data: {
        labels: xValues,
        datasets: [{
          //label: 'set of ' + parameter,
          fill: false,
          //lineTension: 0,
          backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,255,1.0)",
          borderColor: "rgba(0,0,255,0.1)",
          data: yValues,
          showLine: true,
          spanGaps: true
        }]
      },
      options: {
        legend: { display: false }
      }
    });
    chartMap.set(newChart, chart);
    chart.data.datasets[0].data.push(i.value);
    chart.data.labels.push(time);
    chart.update();
  }

  updatePanel(paramList, valueList);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like that when you add a new part to the inner html it has some weird behaviour with chart.js, if you first make all the divs with forms and canvasses and then create the charts it works fine:

```js
var xValues = [50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150];
var yValues = [7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 10, 11, 14, 14, 15];

function displayPanel(i) {
  var panel = document.getElementById('panel');
  panel.innerHTML += `
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
             <form>
                <label id="paramname_${i}" for="paramvalue">${i}</label>
                <input type="text" id="paramvalue_${i}" name="param" value=${i} readonly>  
              </form>
         </div>
         <div id="chart_${i}" class="column">
             <canvas id="myChart${i}" style="width:100%;max-width:600px"></canvas>
         </div>`;
}

function createChart(i) {
  new Chart("myChart" + i, {
    type: "line",
    data: {
      labels: xValues,
      datasets: [{
        fill: false,
        lineTension: 0,
        backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,255,1.0)",
        borderColor: "rgba(0,0,255,0.1)",
        data: yValues
      }]
    },
    options: {
      legend: {
        display: false
      },
      scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            min: 6,
            max: 16
          }
        }],
      }
    }
  });
}

function createUI(k) {
  for (i = 0; i < k; i++) {
    displayPanel(i);
  }

  for (i = 0; i < k; i++) {
    createChart(i);
  }
}

createUI(3)
```

```css
<style>.column {
  float: left;
  align-self: right;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.row {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <div id="panel"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks it worked for me.